# InfluxDb 1.8 retrieving time as subquery for main query

Tags: subquery, influxdb

I am trying to create a query that retrieves all data from one table using a start time retrieved from a second table.

1. Retrieving my latest start time

SELECT last("timeAsString") FROM InitializedApplicationEvent

Returns:
"2020-08-26T20:41:01.762Z"

2. Retrieving ids after that time works

SELECT "idAsField" FROM "Ids" where time >='2020-08-26T20:41:01.762Z'

3. But what I want is a sub query to get the time

SELECT "idAsField" FROM "Ids" where time >= (SELECT last("timeAsString") FROM "InitializedApplicationEvent")

Is there a way to do this with InfluxDB 1.8?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to Query the Ids after latest application start time and only those that have the "inActiveConfiguration" flag set to true.

1. "SHOW TAG VALUES FROM ..." will not work since tag values are not associated with a timestamp in InfluxDB.
2. You must put the id value in both a tag and a field. This allows you to create following Grafana variables with the following queries:

ApplicationStartTime:

SELECT last("timeAsString") FROM InitializedApplicationEvent

Id:

SELECT "last","inActiveConfiguration" from (SELECT last("IdAsField"),"inActiveConfiguration" FROM "Ids" where time >= ${ApplicationStartTime:sqlstring} group by Id) where "inActiveConfiguration"='true'

The one caveat is that these variables only get refreshed "On Dashboard Load". A restriction of Grafana variables.